# ASP.Net Response.Redirect emulate Back Button

Tags: asp.net, back, response.redirect

I am trying to diagnose some behavior on our asp.net based website. Following is the scenario:

User is on page1 and executes query that populates a GridView with data and a hyperlink that redirects to page2.

User clicks on the hyperlink and is redirected to page2 where they can edit data. At the bottom of page2 is a Cancel button that should take the user back to page1.

I would like to have the Cancel button return the user to page1 with their search results populated. This works if the click the Back button on my browser but I cannot emulate this behavior with a response.redirect.

I've tried a number of combinations of the following:

reponse.redirect(request.url.tostring())

and every instance seems to refer to page2 and NOT page1

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This will depend a bit on which version of .net you are using.  In .net Core, the headers on the Request have the info you need.

```
Request.Headers["Referer"]
```

This has the full url with the query string.  You can catch this in the controller and set it to a value on the view model (or stuff it in the view bag).

```
if (Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("Referer"))
    ViewBag.Referer = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"];
else
    ViewBag.Referer = "";
```

Then use a `string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Referer)` in the view.  I added the check for safety reasons, why if they got to the page directly without a link?

You can also use `Request.Headers.TryGetValue`.  It is a little safer as there could be duplicate headers but there really shouldn't be, expecially here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, it still isn't working, let me clarify what is happening. I've added some breakpoints and can expand a bit. In page2, I've put a breakpoint at the Page_Load event and if I print out the request.headers("Referer") it correctly refers to page1. 

On page2 I have a "Back" button that should take the user back to page1 however if I click the "Back" button, it fires a page_load event, and now the request.headers("referer") points to page2 and thus I can't return the user to their original query on page1

Comment: Post the code for the "Back" button.  What you should be doing is sending the value you save in the ViewBag (as I showed above) into the href of the  anchor tag which is your button.  My guess is that your button is a "submit" and is trying to submit a form.

Comment: All i'm doing in the "Back" button event is call response.redirect and passing it the stored value as you suggested. After some further investigation, i think I need to determine if the button is causing the post back and if it is, don't assign the referer

Comment: Yes, it is causing some sort of post back to the server.  Change it to an anchor tag instead.  I think you are making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "change it to an anchor tag"?

Comment: `<a href="@ViewBag.Referer" class="btn btn-default">My Button</a>`    Put that on your page and see what happens.

Comment: I'm actually using asp.net so the button declaration looks like:
<asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="Back" CssClass="submitButtonLarge" 
            Visible="true" Height="50px" Width="150px"  />

Comment: Which version of asp.net are you using?

Comment: i'm using VS Pro 2012

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141469/discussion-between-kevin-and-nurdyguy).

Comment: So, I did get your suggestion implemented however it didn't really solve the issue.

I was hoping to return back to the cached page1 via the Back button, using your code, I can go back to page1 however it doesn't contain the cached/searched data.

Comment: You won't be able to get the cached page but as long as the query string is in place it should reload the data for the page.